# Open date picker to a specific date without a default value for ng-model

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I´m using a UI-Bootstrap **0.6.0** Datepicker component. I´ve two questions:

1. Is it possible to open it on a specific date, in example 01-january-2014, without setting a default value for the ng-model. I mean, when the page is loaded, I just want to display a placeholder, but when clicked, the calendar should be opened on 01-january-2014.
2. Is it possible to remove the buttons bar at the bottom (Today, Weeks, Clear, Close)?

I know this can be done in latter versions, but please, take into account, I have a restriction to do it in 0.6.0 version. I cannot migrate to a latter one.

Please, see a plunker with tests in `http://plnkr.co/edit/qCo1YbDQNIAvMUf9iDZJ?p=preview`

```
<input type="text" 
               show-weeks="false"
               datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" 
               ng-model="dt" 
               min="minDate" 
               max="'2015-06-22'" 
               datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
               date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
              />
```

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the attribute "init-date"
2. You can disable the buttons bar by adding this attribute:

```html
data-show-button-bar="false"
```